# mat-form-field occupying more area causing other controls moving away from it

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular`, `Angular Material` and `CSS`

My `mat-form-field` code is as below..

```
<mat-form-field  class="custom-form-field" appearance="outline" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 0px;">
    <input style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" matInput type="text" id="onSearch" (keyup)="keyUp($event)">
    <mat-icon matPrefix class="centered-icon">search</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

And with this the front-end looks like this while I inspect that part

[image: Subscriber Groups]

The `mat-form-field` is occupying the extra Green color so the checkboxes are coming down.

Even if I set `padding-bottom: 0px` or `margin-bottom: 0px`, still it is occupying that space.

How to remove that space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the CSS

```
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
 }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6pxnxi) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`